# Indicating the answers with high number of up-votes

Tags: feature-request, up-votes

There are many cases on different branches of SX that I see some answers with a very high up-vote are buried under a lot of answers with a far lower up-vote. Most of the time I end up copying and pasting the accepted answer and yet sometimes there are many better solutions down there. I have two questions:

1. Why these are not sorted by their up-vote, right under the accepted answer?
2. Isn't it a good idea to inform the viewer of the question that there exist answers with higher up-vote than the accepted one? (or even comparable to the accepted one)

As an example see the answer with 22 votes here:
[How do I repeat a theorem number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number)

Comment: Regarding 1. - Yes, they are sorted like this if you click the "votes" tab, unless a highly-upvoted answer is also high downvoted. Regarding 2 - See 1.

Comment: I just saw that "votes" tab! thanks!

Comment: @HDE226868 By default, the accepted answer is at top, regardless of votes, so the second question is still valid. See this example: https://superuser.com/questions/365214/how-can-i-find-out-the-password-complexity-policy/